# How to limit a MySQL Distance Query

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm trying to preform a distance calculation to return a listing of places within a certain distance. This is based on using a zip code database and determining the distance from the origin to each location. What I want to do is limit the results to be within a certain distance from the origin, but I'm having trouble with my MySQL query. Here's the basic query:

```
SELECT *, 
       ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(42.320271)) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(42.320271)) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(-88.462832 - zip_longitude))))) * 69.09 AS distance 
  FROM locations 
LEFT JOIN zip_codes USING (zip_code)  
 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

This works great and gives me all the info for each location including the distance from the origin zip code...exactly what I want. However, I want to limit the results to fall within a certain distance (i.e., WHERE distance<=50).

My question and problem is I can't figure out where to include (WHERE distance<=50) into the query above to make it all work. Everything I've tried gives me an error message. Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options:

1. Restate the logic in the WHERE clause so you can filter by it:

   ```
      SELECT *, 
             ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(42.320271)) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(42.320271)) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(-88.462832 - zip_longitude))))) * 69.09 AS distance 
        FROM locations 
   LEFT JOIN zip_codes USING (zip_code)  
       WHERE (ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(42.320271)) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(42.320271)) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(-88.462832 - zip_longitude))))) * 69.09) <= 50
    ORDER BY distance
   ```

   This is the better choice, because it requires only one pass over the data.  Sadly, it requires you to duplicate the logic -- if you were using the information in the `GROUP BY` or `HAVING` clause, MySQL supports referencing a column alias in those.
2. Use a subquery:

   ```
     SELECT x.* 
       FROM (SELECT *, 
                    ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(42.320271)) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(42.320271)) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(-88.462832 - zip_longitude))))) * 69.09 AS distance 
               FROM locations 
          LEFT JOIN zip_codes USING (zip_code)) x
      WHERE x.distance <= 50 
   ORDER BY x.distance
   ```

Comment: This is perfect, you rock. I wouldn't have thought to try it that way. Thanks!

Comment: Your first solution worked great for me thanks! - Though it does seem a little wasteful to perform the proximity calculatuion twice?

Comment: @Haroldo: SQL is SET based, not procedural.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to wrap your query in another query and put the condition and order there.  This should work:

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT *, ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(42.320271)) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) + COS(RADIANS(42.320271)) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) * COS(RADIANS(-88.462832 - zip_longitude))))) * 69.09 AS distance FROM locations LEFT JOIN zip_codes USING (zip_code)
) WHERE distance <= 50 ORDER BY distance ASC
```

The middle line is your query without the `ORDER BY`

Comment: Sounds simple enough, but when I tried it it doesn't work. I get an error: #1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is actually using HAVING instead of WHERE, also i moved the last bracket of your ROUND function behind the 69.09, which gives you a higher precision in calculation but still returns a rounded number:

```
SELECT *, 
    ROUND(DEGREES(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS(42.320271)) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude))
    + COS(RADIANS(42.320271)) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) 
    * COS(RADIANS(-88.462832 - zip_longitude)))) * 69.09,2) AS distance 
FROM locations 
LEFT JOIN zip_codes USING (zip_code)
HAVING distance <= 50
ORDER BY distance ASC
```

So basically your query was fine, you just need to add the HAVING clause and you may want to fix that rounding to get better results. In my project i used following very similar formula discarding the outer DEGREES function and multiplying by earths circumference:

```
ROUND(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('42.320271')) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) 
+ COS(RADIANS('42.320271')) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude))
* COS(RADIANS(zip_longitude - '-88.462832'))) * 3963.190592,3) AS distance
```

and by changing the multiplier at the end, you have kilometers instead of miles:

```
ROUND(ACOS(SIN(RADIANS('42.320271')) * SIN(RADIANS(zip_latitude)) 
+ COS(RADIANS('42.320271')) * COS(RADIANS(zip_latitude))
* COS(RADIANS(zip_longitude - '-88.462832'))) * 6378.137,3) AS distance
```